# Combinatorics of tickets (same number as many as three times.)

Tags: combinatorics

Here's the question I'm trying to solve:

> In a lottery game, players choose 6 numbers between 1 and 24. Suppose players may choose the same number as many as three times. such as $\{2,2,5,20,22,23\}$ and $\{7,7,7,10,10,19\}$, How many tickets are possible?

I'm trying to consider the following cases:

1. 6 distinct numbers: $\binom {24}6$
2. 1 pair and 4 distinct numbers: $\binom {24}1\times \binom {23}4$
3. 2 pairs and 2 distinct numbers: $\binom {24}2\times \binom {22}2$
4. 3 pairs: $\binom {24}3$
5. 1 triplet, 3 distinct: $\binom {24}1\times \binom {23}3$
6. 1 triplet, 1 pair, 1 distinct: $\binom {24}1\times \binom {23}1\times \binom{22}1$
7. 2 triplets: $\binom {24}2$

I'm not pretty sure if my answer looks correct, and I'm especially confused at case 6: can I represent that as $\binom {24}2\times\binom {22}1$? Is there a better way to think about this question? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is $C_1,\dots,C_6$? This isn't standard notation, and it doesn't seem like you're using it quite right.

Comment: Choose notation, the subscript is odd.  Pretty sure your 7 is wrong as it would include cases where the same numbers are picked in all triples, which isn't allowed

Comment: @ndhanson3 Thanks for the comment, but that I want to say 24 choose 6.

Comment: Ohhh try "{}_{24}C_6" to get that 24 as a subscript. ${}_{24}C_6$

Comment: @ndhanson3 Got it. Thanks

Comment: @Alan Thanks for the correction, it should be $\binom {24}1\cdot\binom {23}1$, is that right?

Comment: then 22C1 for the third triple

Comment: @Alan There're 6 numbers in total, so there're only 2 triples, right?

Comment: Your computations against the $7$ cases is ok, your afterthought is not. Case $7$ is also ok, you are choosing $2$ numbers from $24$ and forming two triplets from them.

Comment: The number of cases will be reduced if you calculate the number of combinations that does not work.

Comment: Oh right, sorry.  I was thinking it was the three  doubles.

Comment: @true blue anil Thanks, but I feel like it also makes sense to me to choose 1 number from 24 numbers and another one from the rest 23. Are there any differences between these two cases?

Comment: @Asher2211 Thanks for the comment, in that case, should I consider the same number appears more than 3 times?

Comment: Yes, if you consider that the same number appears more than 3 times then you will have only $4$ cases.

Comment: If you choose the two numbers one by one for case $7$, you will double count: $AB$ and $BA$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your working is correct. Specifically on case $6$ that you raised a question,

$1$ triple, $1$ pair and $1$ single: $ \displaystyle {24 \choose 1}{23 \choose 1} {22 \choose 1}$ is correct.

You could have also first chosen the $3$ numbers and then assign one as triple, one as pair and one as a single.

So it can be also be written as $\displaystyle {24 \choose 3} \cdot 3! \ $ or as $ \displaystyle {24 \choose 2} \cdot 2! \cdot {22 \choose 1}$

Another approach to do this is to use generating function, if you are familiar with it.

Each number can be selected $0 - 3$ times and there are $24$ numbers so generating function is,

$(1+x+x^2+x^3)^{24}$

Now we look for coefficient of $x^6$ in it as each ticket has $6$ numbers and that is $467820$. Your answer matches.

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Comment: @IGY you are welcome. I will also suggest try and find combinations that do not work - a number $4$ times + one pair or $2$ distincts; a number $5$ times; a number $6$ times. That gives $7200$ and subtract it from total number of combinations ${29 \choose 6}$.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not studied generating functions, I would suggest using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). The problem is equivalent to putting $6$ identical balls into $24$ distinct bins, minus cases with any one bin violating constraint by having $4$ or more balls, thus

$\dbinom{6+24-1}{24-1} - \dbinom{24}{1}\dbinom{2+24-1}{24-1} =\boxed {467 820}$